# html + js - checkbox disabled by radio

Tags: html, forms, input, checkbox, radio-button

I'm a beginner, so I'd like to ask if someone could give me a hand in building a research form in HTML (with JS) that must have 2 checkboxes and can be disabled by the third.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Do you like fishing?:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="fish"></td>
  </tr><br />
  <tr>
    <td>Or do you like jogging?:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="wake"></td>
  </tr><br />
  <tr>
    <td>None of that:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="" id="none"></td>
</tr>
</table>`
```

My goal is to use the third cell to cancel the first and second options.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your questions tells me you shouldn't use checkboxes because you are asking the user to choose one answer or the other. Radio buttons are perfect for this. Checkboxes allow multiple choices to be selected.

If you want to "disable" items you should use javascript to set the "disabled" attribute to your questions when the "none of the above" is ticked.

Disabled input fields are not in the POST array when the form is submitted.

From the given question you have supplied you should use a radio button group. This will only allow one of the three available answers your question is asking the user to complete.

example: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm